# what's the meaning of "hayseed grammar"?

Tags: meaning

> "*With his hayseed grammar, denim shirt and
>   lifetime-member NRA cap, Dad would have always been out of place at
>   Harvard, but his scarring intensified the effect."*

The word "hayseed" means: a person from the country, especially one who is simple and unsophisticated."denim shirt" and "lifetime-member NRA cap" relate to Dad's clothes. But what about the "grammar"? Does it mean his grammar book?

The full text:

MY PARENTS ARRIVED AS the leaves began to turn, when campus was at its
most beautiful, the reds and yellows of autumn mingling with the
burgundy of colonial brick. With his **hayseed grammar**, denim shirt and
lifetime-member NRA cap, Dad would have always been out of place at
Harvard, but his scarring intensified the effect.

Comment: You already pretty much answered the question yourself.  A hayseed is "a person from the country, especially one who is simple and unsophisticated", so *hayseed grammar* is grammar of the kind "hayseed": the kind that a person from the country, especially one who is simple and unsophisticated, would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hayseed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hayseed) here is used figuratively to refer to:

> - an unsophisticated person from a rural area;

so the grammar, that's the language they speak is sort of basic, unsophisticated.

(Dictionary.com)